# Cannot trace on the status if connected to API Server or not

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I am creating a sign in page where in connected to API to retrieve event details using passcode that will be inputted in a textfield,  but the display message "*Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later*" is the only thing that appears. I can't track if I have error in connection or the codes I wrote. Kindly help me and check my code if there is something wrong or missing. Thank you.

```
    //Read values from textfield
    let eventcode = appCodeTextField.text

    //Check if required fields are not empty
    if  (eventcode?.isEmpty)!
    {
    //Display alert message here
     self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Please input event code.")
        print("empty")
     return
    }


    //Send HTTP Request to perform Sign in
   let myUrl = URL(string: "http://hopprlab.com/api/events/passcodechecker/(event_id)")
    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST" //Compose a query string
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let postString = ["eventcode": eventcode!]  as [String: String]

    do
    {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print (error.localizedDescription)
        displayMessage(userMessage: "Network Error!")
        return
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        self.removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: myActivityIndicator)

        if error != nil
        {
            self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        //Convert response sent to server side code to a NSDictionary object:

        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {

                if parseJSON["errorMessageKey"] != nil {
                    self.displayMessage(userMessage: parseJSON["errorMessage"] as! String)
                    return
                }

                //Now we can acess value
                let event_id = parseJSON["event_id"] as? String

                let saveEventId: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set((event_id)!, forKey: "event_id")

                print("The event id save result \(saveEventId)")

                if (event_id?.isEmpty)!
                {
                 self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")

                    return
                }
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 let dashBoardPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashBoardViewController") as! DashBoardViewController
                 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                 appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = dashBoardPage

                }
            } else {
                //Display an Alert dialog with a friendly error message
                self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")

        }

    } catch {
        self.removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: myActivityIndicator)

        //Display an Alert dialog with a friendly error message
        self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request. Please try again later")
        print(error)

    }


    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Seems like you're showing the same error message for all errors, which in some cases is fine if you're going for user friendly messages, but for testing, changing them to something more descriptive will help you a lot. To take it a step further, you'll be better off putting breakpoints where all the error messages are and then figuring out what's causing the issue

Comment: @DavidLiaw Hi, I tried to put breakpoint in line ' let postString = ["eventcode": eventcode!]  as [String: String]' as I viewed the content of _postString_ the value is empty. How can I sign in using event code stored in APIServer? Thank you

Comment: I think you may have your logic backward because `(eventcode?.isEmpty)!` checks if it isn't empty, and since the next statement is an error I think this is your issue

Comment: @DavidLiaw I will back track on that. Thank you so much. If you don't mind can you give me some reference in creating Sign In Page using passcode that is connected to REST API. Thank you so much

Comment: That's kind of a broad, there are many ways of doing it. At a high level you'd pretty much have to make a POST request using a networking library or NSURLSession  when a user hits sign in and then handle the response. Every REST API is different so domain specific implementation is up for you to figure out. There are many tutorials and open source projects that you could look through.